# .NET MVC - Multiple GET methods in the same controller using ActionName()

Tags: .net, rest, routes

Following routes are in my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
// routing for /profile/
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "profile",
    routeTemplate: "users/{userid}/profil",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", userid = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

// routing for /messages/
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "messages",
    routeTemplate: "users/{userid}/messages",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", userid = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And this is the according code in the Controller:

```
public class UserController {

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("profile")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetProfile(int userid) {}


    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("messages")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMessages(int userid) {}

}
```

So basically I want to have two methods in the same controller which both take the same parameters, but are mapped to different URLs.
Right now I keep getting an error about multiple actions being found - even though I have a distinction of the ActionName attribute.

What am I doing wrong? Can I have two GET methods in the same controller, taking the same input but being called on different URLs?

Thanks!

Comment: You are aware of the typo in your routes for profil ? your actionname is profile

Comment: Ah, thank you. This wasn't the real code though, so that couldn't have been the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to specifically add action name on the routing definition ?

i.e.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "profile",
routeTemplate: "users/{userid}/profil",
defaults: new { controller = "User", action="profil", userid = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

);